# Identifier expected error with KeyListener/KeyListener methods

Tags: java

I'm working on a very, very simple internet browser in Java. I've gotten most of it down, but I'm having trouble getting the "hit enter to send URL" part. Specifically, I'm getting this error when I use the keyTyped() method:

`Browser.java:34: error: ';' expected
                        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
                                            ^
Browser.java:34: error: ';' expected
                        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
                                                       ^`

I originally thought I missed a couple of '}' and '{' tags somewhere, but I've scoured my code and everything seems to be where its supposed to be, so I'm stumped.

My Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Browser extends JFrame {
    public Browser(){
        setTitle("The next Google Chrome");
        Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize(600,700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new BrowserPanel());
        setVisible(true);
    }

public String URL;

class BrowserPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
    public BrowserPanel()
    {
        JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
        field.addKeyListener(this);
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(30, 50);
        JTextArea dummy = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        add(field);
        add(scroll);
        String response;
        String checkTitle = "YA GOOFED.";
        String mainBody = "REAL BAD.";

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                try
                {   
                    URL = field.getText();
                    String ind = "http://";
                    int check = URL.indexOf("http://");
                    int index = ind.length();
                    String sub = URL.substring(index);
                    String filepath = sub.substring(sub.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    String webaddress = URL.substring(index, URL.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    if(check == -1)
                        area.append("This is not a proper URL.\n Please add 'http://' to the beginning of your address and try again.");
                    else
                    {
                        Socket s = new Socket(webaddress, 80);
                        PrintWriter send = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        send.print("GET " + filepath + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                        send.print("Host: " + webaddress + "\r\n");
                        send.print("\r\n");
                        send.flush();
                        while((response = read.readLine())!= null)
                        {
                            dummy.append(response + "\n");
                        }
                        checkTitle = dummy.getText();
                        int title1 = checkTitle.indexOf("<title>");
                        int title2 = checkTitle.indexOf("</title>");
                        int body1 = checkTitle.indexOf("<body class="+"\"innerpage\""+">");
                        int body2 = checkTitle.indexOf("</body>");
                        String preMainBody = checkTitle.substring(body1, body2);
                        String preTitle = checkTitle.substring(title1 , title2);
                        String title = preTitle.substring(7);
                        mainBody = preMainBody.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>","");
                        area.append(mainBody);
                        setTitle(title);
                        System.out.println(title);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException i)
                {
                    i.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

  public static void main (String[] args){
        new Browser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively trying to declare those methods inside the constructor at present.

You need a closing `}` somewhere before the method declarations start. It looks like you have balanced the braces, so you'd also likely need to remove one from the end of the class too.

It's hard to know exactly your intent, but I suspect it would be between the `add(scroll)` and `String response` lines.

Comment: Or, exactly, the methods must be moved out of the constructor. (There is already a closing `}`.)

Comment: Yep, I had to move them out of the BrowserPanel constructor. Now I just gotta get this addKeyListener working and all will be well and I can *try* to sleep qq